# linear-gradient on text not browserproof

Tags: css, text

My issue is purely crossbrowser and i have tried almost everything. From importing the code from http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ to playing with every possible combination and prefixes.

I have a H1 class wich is styled (primarely) :

```css
.welcome h1 {
  line-height: 1em;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 120px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#7c6510, #b9a044, #7c6510);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 17px #b9a044;
}
```

```html
<div class="welcome-container"><div class="welcome text-center"><h1>Pluche Lingerie</h1></div></div>
```

This works great in Chrome and Safari. But not in Mozilla and IE (v11)

So i have tried this:

```css
.welcome h1 {
  line-height: 1em;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 120px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#7c6510, #b9a044, #7c6510);
  background: #7c6510;
  /* Old browsers */
  /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #7c6510 0%, #b9a044 50%, #7c6510 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #7c6510), color-stop(50%, #b9a044), color-stop(100%, #7c6510));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #7c6510 0%, #b9a044 50%, #7c6510 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #7c6510 0%, #b9a044 50%, #7c6510 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #7c6510 0%, #b9a044 50%, #7c6510 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #7c6510 0%, #b9a044 50%, #7c6510 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#7c6510', endColorstr='#7c6510', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-8 */
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -o-background-clip: text;
  -o-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -ms-background-clip: text;
  -ms-text-fill-color: transparent;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 17px #b9a044;
}
```

```html
<div class="welcome-container"><div class="welcome text-center"><h1>Pluche Lingerie</h1></div></div>
```

And each combination possible (also without trying to make this work for IE). All i get is a beautifull background gradient in IE and Mozilla with white font. I have no idea what i am doing wrong, why does the:

```css
-webkit-background-clip: text;
   -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
```

and the versions for moz and ie not work?

Thanks!

Comment: background-clip: text is a non w3c extension, supported only in webkit

Comment: And what can i do best to make this work in all browsers?

Comment: I'am not a css genieus, just fuguring out :-) i've used SVG in code above, but it does not seem to work. Perhaps you could provide me with a more complete answer or perhaps cases and examples where this does work. I would be really greatfull.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/arjwsL1m/1/ but svg is not supported in ie-8

Comment: Thanks @vitorino!

This was exactly what i needed, works like a charm!! I only can not get the shadow to work the way i want. I see the shadow in your example, but i want it to be goldish with a blurry effect. Did some reading and tried other svg filter combinations but did not have any luck. 

But my main problem is solved!

Thanks again!!

Comment: you welcome :) check this http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/arjwsL1m/2/ if it meets your requirement